# empty EHLO from all around the web, is it a bot?

Tags: email, smtp

I've been getting this since a few weeks ago:

```
Transcript of session follows.

 Out: 220 www.example.com ESMTP
 In:  EHLO
 Out: 501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
 In:  HELO
 Out: 501 Syntax: HELO hostname
 In:  QUIT
 Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye


For other details, see the local mail logfile
```

These connections come from all the internet, from 2.0.0.0/8 to 221.0.0.0/8

My question is NOT how to stop it (-j DROP --dport 25) or how to stop receiving the mails (remove protocol in postfix main.cf)

My question is simple: why? is it a misconfigured bot? I googled and saw messages related to this since 2006. I get 30 of these a day or more. I'm waaaay curious about this. Anybody has more information about it? when did it begin? what's going on?

That's all, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of bots don't get the hostname right.  I suspect that is what you are seeing.  Looking at my mail database, I only see one record like this.  However, a lot of bots trigger response delays and give up before they get to the EHLO/HELO step.

I don't know the Postfix capabilities, but I delay answering the connection for several seconds if the DNS entries for the server aren't good.  A proper mail server will wait and connect.  Most Bots don't wait around, likely because they want to deliver messages as quickly as possibly, not as reliably as possible.

Try doing a host look-up on the addresses which are failing.  Valid mail servers will return a pointer to a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name).  This FQDN will almost always return the IP address you started with.  If not, you likely have a Bot trying to connect.  As the name is blank, this is most likely.

Comment: Thank you, initial delay in postfix I think not but it can delay answers after a soft_limit number of errors. Yes it does reverse and most are home users (comcast, rr, virginmedia, etc) and some others don't resolve (unknown).

Comment: @Mario The reverse lookups you are getting are typical of SpamBots.  I would expect forward lookups on the names you get from the reverse lookups most of the time.